# text box that allows computer to recognize letter in the order they appear

Tags: javascript

I am a fairly new programmer and I am programming a encrypt-er.

so what I need is a text-box that allows the viewer to type the plain text and have the computer recognize which letter came first, second, third, ext......

for example if a viewer typed "test" in the text box. I would need a way for the computer to recognize that "t" came first and distinguish it from the other letters in some way.

what is the best way to do this.

here is the code I have so far

```
function Encode() {

  var myNewEncode = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewEncode.length >= 20) {
  alert('text is limeted to 20 charictors');
  return;
  }

  var Encode = document.getElementById('Encode');
  Encode.innerHTML = myNewEncode;

}

})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  Have you any code so far?

Comment: @nycynik I am clueless about how to wright this type of code, thats why I came here. so I don't have any code. but I will add an example of what I need done.

Comment: Why does the order in which the individual letters were typed matter? If the user accidentally types in "est", then realises they left off the first "t" and goes back to insert it, why wouldn't you treat the resulting value of "test" the same as if they'd typed "t", "e", "s", "t" in the first place?

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry for the miscommunication with the title. I tried other titles but  stackoverflow said that they didn't meet requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in jQuery:**

```
 $(function() {
        $('#mytext').keypress(function(evnt) {
               console.log(evnt.key)
         });
     })
```

**in javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("myField").addEventListener("keypress",function(evnt){
            console.log(evnt.key);
  })
```

You can try this code it will solve your problem. `mytext` is your input text box. Each time you type in a character it will `evnt.key` will return that particular character.

Comment: this solution looks good to me.  If it is a valid answer, you should mark it answered.

Comment: I,m still working on getting it worked into my code. but I think your answer is correct.